# "If" condition is not working. How can i compare them both. Also i have tried the value into integer type but it still wont work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var v= document.getElementById('btn');

v.addEventListener('click', action);

var selection = document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect01');

function action(e) { 
  document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect01');
  console.log(selection.value);
  var b = parseInt("selection.value");
  console.log(typeof(b));
  if (b === 2) {
    console.log("congo number is 1");
  } 
  else { 
    console.log('not');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  `var b = parseInt("selection.value");` to  `var b = parseInt(selection.value);`
since you are parsing the value which is string but string also should be integer like so parseInt('1') will work but parseInt('demo') will not work. so you are doing like this `parseInt("selection.value");` which will never work.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
var b = parseInt("selection.value");
```

You are trying the parse the literal string `"selection value"` into an integer, instead of the value of the field `value` of whatever `selection` refers to.

Should be:

```
var b = parseInt(selection.value);
```

Comment: you could mention the radix parameter of `parseInt` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this line `var b = parseInt("selection.value");` It will give an undefined

Replace that line with this var `b = parseInt(selection.value,10)`